# Module 'turtle has no listen member. Module turtle has no 'onkeymember.'

Tags: python

I am currently trying to learn python in Visual Studio Code. I"m using python 3.8.2 I'm following a reliable tutorial to help me learn python better (I learn best visually.) The project I'm trying to work on is the space invaders game and I keep having a problem with my code. The errors are (**Module 'turtle' has no 'listen' member) and (Module 'turtle' has no 'onkey' member)**  Help is appreciated. Also import turtle and import os are on separate lines. Not all on one line. also import turtle is there it just won"t copy to the code. trust me it"s there. I also installed the python extension. [Python Errors][1]

````
import os

#Set up the screen
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor("black")
wn.title("Space Invaders")

#Draw boarder
border_pen = turtle.Turtle()
border_pen.speed(0)
border_pen.color("white")
border_pen.penup()
border_pen.setposition(-300,-300)
border_pen.pendown()
border_pen.pensize(3)
for side in range (4):
    border_pen.fd(600)
    border_pen.lt(90)
border_pen.hideturtle()

#Create the player turtle
player =turtle.Turtle()
player.color('blue')
player.shape('triangle')
player.penup()
player.speed(0)
player.setposition(0, -250)
player.setheading(90)

playerspeed = 15

#Move the player left and right
def move_left():
    x = player.xcor()
    x-=playerspeed
    player.setx(x)

    #Create keyboard bindings
    turtle.listen()
    turtle.onkey(move_left, "Left")








wn.mainloop() ```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6u7IB.png
````

Comment: I was"t sure if I should have posted the image because I saw Images are useful in a post but make sure the post is still clear without them. – DKRacingFan just now

Comment: Please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You need to `import turtle` somewhere near the top and then unindent :

```
turtle.listen ()
turtle.onkey(move_left, "Left")
```

Works for me ;)

Comment: I fixed it just had to install an older version of python. I'm working on a BK project now.